# Unable to publish PostGIS layer to GeoServer

Tags: postgis, geoserver, layers

I am trying to connect QGIS, PostgreSQL (PostGIS) + GeoServer.

I've brought my PostGIS database to the server, created a "store" and now I'm trying to publish a layer. I went to Layers- Choose my layer- Publish- Edit Layer (Data/Publishing)- configure everything there- SAVE and nothing happens... I can't see my layer in "Layer Preview"

So maybe my configuring was wrong. I chose the native SRS, point style, authority name: admin, authorithy URL (is it the server's URL?).

What is layer identifier, as well?

Answer (score 2):

I have a tutorial you can follow at http://ian01.geog.psu.edu/geoserver_docs/data/naturalearth/index.html which should get you started. With out more information about what is actually going wrong (e.g. the log entries) it's hard to see what might be specifically wrong in your case.

Comment: the log says something like this:"2012-06-13 13:09:43,003 WARN [geoserver.web] - Unable to find property: 'format.wms.image/png; mode=8bit' for component:  [class=org.geoserver.web.demo.MapPreviewPage]
"    I did succed publishing a layer on another computer. I don't know why it doesn't work on this one. Sorry :(

Comment: Link appears to be broken.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out [Publishing a PostGIS table](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/gettingstarted/postgis-quickstart/index.html) and can try example data which links publish on it whether your file is correct or not.

Beside this you can visit [here](http://www.gistutor.com/geoserver/11-beginner-geoserver-tutorials/42-how-to-connect-geoserver-to-postgis-spatial-datasets.html) - How to Connect GeoServer to PostGIS Spatial Datasets  for secondary alternative.

Comment: i've already visited these links. I followed the steps recommended there. But I didn't find  anything about "authority name"/ "layer identifier"

Comment: Second link appears to be broken.